# T-sql: Highlight invoice numbers if they occur in a payment description field

Tags: t-sql, replace, sql-server-2017

I have two sql-server tables: bills and payments. I am trying to create a VIEW to highlight the bill numbers if they occur in the payment description field. For example:

TABLE bll

```
|bllID     | bllNum   |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | qwerty123|
| 2        | qwerty345|
| 3        | 1234     |
```

TABLE payments

```
|paymentID | description                        |
| -------- | ---------------------------------- |
| 1        | payment of qwerty123 and qwerty345 |
```

I want to highlight both the 'qwerty123' and 'qwerty345' strings by adding html code to it. The code I have is this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(payments.description, 
               COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 bll.bllNum
                         FROM   bll
                         WHERE  COALESCE(bll.bllNum, '') <> '' AND 
                                PATINDEX('%' + bll.bllNum + '%', payments.description) > 0), ''),
               '<font color=red>' + 
               COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 bll.bllNum
                         FROM   bll
                         WHERE  COALESCE(bll.bllNum, '') <> '' AND 
                                PATINDEX('%' + bll.bllNum + '%', payments.description) > 0), '') + 
               '</font>')
FROM payments
```

This works but only for the first occurrence of a bill number. If the description field has more than one bill number, the consecutive bill numbers are not highlighted. So in my example 'qwerty123' gets highlighted, but not 'qwerty345'

I need to highlight all occurrences. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Presumably a web front-end is consuming this data, why can the html not be implemented there where it's more appropriate to do so?

Comment: This isn't something for T-SQL but for something that supports Regex Replacement (presumably your invoices have a format, such as `[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]` you can look for ). The *only* way you could do it in T-SQL would be with a *huge* recursive replace; iterating on all your invoice numbers or the format of them. That will be awfully non-performant.

Comment: That's a job for the *client application*, not SQL, the language, or any SQL database.  SQL is a query language, not a text manipulation language or template engine. Why are you trying to use SQL in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that this is not a task best done in the database, one possible approach you could try is to use `string_split` to break your description into words and then join this to your Bills, doing your string manipulation on matching rows.

Note, according to the documentation, `string_split` is not 100% guaranteed to retain its correct ordering but always has in my usage. It could always be substituted for an alternative function to work on the same principle.

```
select string_agg (w.word,' ') [Description]
from (
    select 
        case when exists (select * from bill b where b.billnum=s.value)
            then Concat('<font colour="red">',s.value,'</font>') else s.value end word
    from payments p
    cross apply  String_Split(description,' ')s
)w
```

Example [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=371d0017baf8737d5f13d016a92f5c4f)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I understand, I can put code in the front-end application by looping through the bill numbers and replacing them as they are found in the description. Just thought/ hoped there was a simple solution to this using t-sql. But I understand the difficulty.